# To double escape or not to double escape in PHP PCRE functions?

Tags: php, regex

I was looking for a solid article on when double escaping is necessary and when it is not, but I was not able to find anything. Perhaps I didn't look hard enough, because I'm sure there is an explanation out there somewhere, but lets just make it easy to find for the next guy that has this question!

Take for example the following regex patterns:

```
/\n/
/domain\.com/
/myfeet \$ your feet/
```

Nothing ground breaking right? OK, lets use those examples within the context of PHP's preg_match function:

```
$foo = preg_match("/\n/", $bar);
$foo = preg_match("/domain\.com/", $bar);
$foo = preg_match("/myfeet \$ your feet/", $bar);
```

To my understanding, a backslash in the context of a quoted string value escapes the following character, and the expression is being given via a quoted string value.

Would the previous be like doing the folloing, and wouldnt this cause an error?:

```
$foo = preg_match("/n/", $bar);
$foo = preg_match("/domain.com/", $bar);
$foo = preg_match("/myfeet $ your feet/", $bar);
```

Which is not what I want right? those expressions are not the same as above.

Would I not have to write them double escaped like this?

```
$foo = preg_match("/\\n/", $bar);
$foo = preg_match("/domain\\.com/", $bar);
$foo = preg_match("/myfeet \\$ your feet/", $bar);
```

So that when PHP processes the string it escapes the backslash to a backslash which is then left in when its passed to the PCRE interpreter?

Or does PHP just magically know that I want to pass that backslash to the PCRE interpreter... i mean how does it know I'm not trying to `\"` escape a quote that I want to use in my expression? or are only double slashes required when using an escaped quote? And for that matter, would you need to TRIPLE escape a quote? `\\\"` You know, so that the quote is escaped and a double is left over?

Whats the rule of thumb with this?

I just did a test with PHP:

```
$bar = "asdfasdf a\"ONE\"sfda dsf adsf me & mine adsf asdf asfd ";

echo preg_match("/me \$ mine/", $bar);
echo "<br /><br />";
echo preg_match("/me \\$ mine/", $bar);
echo "<br /><br />";
echo preg_match("/a\"ONE\"/", $bar);
echo "<br /><br />";
echo preg_match("/a\\\"ONE\\\"/", $bar);
echo "<br /><br />";
```

Output:

```
0

1

1

1
```

So, it looks like somehow it doesnt really matter for quotes, but for the dollar sign, a double escape is required as I thought.

Comment: *"it looks like somehow it doesnt really matter for quotes, but for the dollar sign, a double escape is requried as I thought."*: The `\$` is an escape sequence for the dollar sign (see the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)), because in double quoted strings, `$...` is interpreted as variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Double quoted strings**

When it comes to escaping inside double quotes, the rule is that PHP will inspect the character(s) immediately following the backslash.

If the neighboring character is in the set `ntrvef\$"` or if a numeric value follows it (rules can be found [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)) it gets evaluated as the corresponding control character or ordinal (hexadecimal or octal) representation, respectively.

It's important to note that if an invalid escape sequence is given, the expression is not evaluated and both the backslash and character remain. This is different from some other languages where an invalid escape sequence would cause an error instead.

E.g. `"domain\.com"` will be left as is.

Note that variables get expanded inside double quotes as well, e.g. `"$var"` needs to be escaped as `"\$var"`.

**Single quotes strings**

Since PHP 5.1.1, any backslash inside single quoted strings (and followed by at least one character) will get printed as is and no variables get substituted either. This is by far the most convenient feature of single quoted strings.

**Regular expressions**

For escaping regular expressions, it's best to leave escaping to `preg_quote()`:

```
$foo = preg_match('/' . preg_quote('mine & yours', '/') . '/', $bar);
```

This way you don't have to worry about which characters need to be escaped, so it works well for user input.

See also: [`preg_quote`](http://www.php.net/preg_quote)

**Update**

You added this test:

```
"/me \$ mine/"
```

This gets evaluated as `"/me $ mine/"`; but in PCRE the `$` has a special meaning (it's an end-of-subject anchor).

```
"/me \\$ mine/"
```

This is evaluated as `"/me \$ mine/"` and so the backslashes is escaped for PHP itself whereas the `$` is escaped for PCRE. This only works by accident btw.

```
$var = 'something';

"/me \\$var mine/"
```

This gets evaluated as `"/me \something"`, so you need to escape the `$` again.

```
"/me \\\$var mine/"
```

Comment: I like this, but its not so much a how i can make this work question, as it is about understanding the semantics involved.

Comment: @SublymeRick Updated my answer by giving an idea of how backslashes in double quotes are evaluated.

Comment: @SublymeRick Explained why you would sometimes need the triple escape :)

Comment: You rock jack. Thanks for the time :)

Comment: plus one just for preg_quote - gold

Comment: I know this is an old question but I am a bit confused. trying to echo `'\'` results in an error but you said `Since PHP 5.1.1, any backslash inside single quoted strings will get printed as is and no variables get substituted either.` So what's going on?

Comment: @CraigPatrickLafferty You're right, I should have been clearer; updated now.

Comment: really surprice me how bad this are in PHP

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes. They prevent escape sequences from occurring.

For example:

```
php > print "hi\n";
hi
php > print 'hi\n';
hi\nphp >
```

Comment: I know this to be true, but what if i want a single quote in my expression then? 'what\'s up?'

Comment: @SublymeRick Except for that escape sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have an invalid escape sequence, PHP actually leaves the characters literally in the string. From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double):

> As in single quoted strings, escaping any other character will result in the backslash being printed too.

I.e. `"\&"` really is interpreted as `"\&"`. There are not that many escape sequences, so in most cases you probably get away with a single backslash. But for consistency, escaping the backslash might be a better choice.

As always: Know what you are doing :)

Comment: oh yeah i guess & isnt a special character and wouldnt need to be escaped, my bad.

Comment: It does not matter anyway, it's more about the backslash ;) It holds for `\.` as well.

Answer (score 0):

OK So I did some more testing and discovered the RULE OF THUMB when encapsulating a PCRE in DOUBLE QUOTES, the following holds true:

`$` - Requires double escape because PHP will interpret that as the beginning of a variable if text is immediately following it. Left unescaped and it will indicate the end of your needle and will break.

`\r\n\t\v` - Special PHP string escapes, single escape required only.

`[\^$.|?*+()` - Special RegEx characters, require single escape only. Double escape does not seem to break expressions when used unnecessarily.

`"` - Quotes are obviously going to have to be escaped due to the encapsulation, but only need to be escaped once.

`\` - Searching for a backslash? Using the double quote encapsulation of your expression, this will require 3 escapes! \\ (four backslashes in total)

Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I'll start saying that all I'll write below is not exactly what happens, but, for clarity, I'll simplify it.

Imagine that **there are two evaluations happening when using regular expressions**: the first being done by PHP and the second being done by PCRE, as if they were separate engines. And for our bad luck,

**PHP AND PCRE EVALUATES THINGS IN DIFFERENT WAYS.**

We have 3 "guys" here: 1) the USER; 2) the PHP and; 3) the PCRE.

The USER communicates with PHP by writing the CODE, which is exactly what you type in a code editor.
PHP then evaluates this CODE and sends another bit of information to PCRE. This bit of information is different from what you typed in your CODE.
PCRE then evaluates it and returns something to PHP, that evaluates this response and returns something to the USER.

I'll explain better in the exemple below. There I'm going to use the backslash ("\") to ilustrate what's going on.

Assume this bit of CODE in a php file:

```
<?php
$sub = "A backslash \ in a string";
$pat1 = "#\#";
$pat2 = "#\\#";
$pat3 = "#\\\#";
$pat4 = "#\\\\#";

echo "sub: ".$sub;
echo "\n\n";

echo "pat1: ".$pat1;
echo "\n";
echo "pat2: ".$pat2;
echo "\n";
echo "pat3: ".$pat3;
echo "\n";
echo "pat4: ".$pat4;
?>
```

This will print:

> ```
> sub: A backslash \ in a string
>
> pat1: #\#
> pat2: #\#
> pat3: #\\#
> pat4: #\\#
> ```

In this exemple, there is no regular expression involved, so there is only the PHP evaluation of the code happening.
**PHP leaves a backslash as is if it doesn't precede any special character**. That's why it prints the backslash correctly in $sub.

PHP evaluates $pat1 and $pat2 EXACTLY the same, because in $pat1 the backslash is left as is, and in $pat2 the first backslash escapes the second, resulting in a single backslash.

Now, in $pat3, the first backslash escapes the second, resulting in one backslash. Then PHP evaluates the third backslash and leaves it as is because it is not preceding anything special. The result is going to be the double backslash.

Now someone could say "but now we have two backslashes again! shouldn't the first one escape the second one again?!"
The answer is "No". After PHP evaluates the first two backslashes into a single one, it doesn't look back again, and keeps moving on evaluating what is next.

At this point you already know what's going on with $pat4: the first backslash escapes the second and the third escapes the fourth, leaving two in the end.

Now that it's clear what PHP is doing to these strings, let's add some more code after the previous one.

```
if (preg_match($pat1, $sub)) echo "test1: true"; else echo "test1: false";
echo "\n";

if (preg_match($pat2, $sub)) echo "test2: true"; else echo "test2: false";
echo "\n";

if (preg_match($pat3, $sub)) echo "test3: true"; else echo "test3: false";
echo "\n";

if (preg_match($pat4, $sub)) echo "test4: true"; else echo "test4: false";
```

And the result is:

> ```
> test1: false
> test2: false
> test3: true
> test4: true
> ```

So, what's going on here is that PHP is not sending "what you typed" in the CODE directly to PCRE. Instead, PHP is sending what it has evaluated previously (which are exactly what we saw above).

For test1 and test2, even though we have written different patterns in the CODE for each test, PHP is sending the same pattern **#\#** to PCRE. The same thing happens for test3 and test4: PHP is sending **#\\#**. So, the results for test1 and test2 are the same, as well as for test3 and test4.

Now, what's going on when PCRE evaluates these patterns? PCRE doesn't act like PHP.

In test1 and test2, when PCRE sees a single backslash escaping nothing special (or nothing at all), it doesn't leave it as is. Instead, it problably thinks "what the hell is this?" and returns an error to PHP (actually, I don't really know what goes on when sending a single backslash to PCRE, searched for this, but still no conclusive). Then PHP takes what we are assuming is an error and evaluates it as "false" and returns that to the rest of the CODE (in this exemple, the *if ()* function).

In test3 and test4, things go as we now expect: PCRE evaluates the first backslash as escaping the second, resulting in a single backslash. That of course matches the $sub string and returns a "successful message" to PHP, which evaluates it as "true".

**ANSWERING QUESTIONS**
Some characters are special to PHP (e.g. **n** for NEW LINE, **t** for TAB).
Some characters are special to PCRE (e.g. **.** (dot) to match any character, **s** to match whitespaces).
And some characters are special to both (e.g. **$** to php is the beginning of the name of a variable and to PCRE it asserts the end of the subject).

That's why you need to escape newlines just once, like this **\n**. PHP will evaluate it as the REAL character NEW LINE and send that to PCRE.

For the dot, if you want to match that specific character, you should use **\.** and PHP will do nothing because the dot isn't a special character to PHP **in a string**. Instead, it will send them as is to PCRE. Now on PCRE, it will "see" a backslash preceding a dot and understand that it should match that specific character. If you use a double escape **\\.** the first backslash will escape the second, leaving you with the same result.

And if you want to match a dollar sign in a string, then you should use **\\\$**. In PHP, the first backslash will escape the second one, leaving a single backslash. Then the third backslash will escape the dollar sign. In the end, the result is **\$**. This is what PCRE will receive. PCRE will see that backslash and understand that the dollar sign is not asserting end of subject, but the literal character.

**QUOTES**

And now we've come to quotes. The problem with them is the fact that PHP evaluates a string in different ways, depending on the quotes used to surround it. Check it out: [Strings](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

All I said until this point is valid for double quotes.
If you try this **'\n'** in single quotes, PHP will evaluate that backslash as a literal one.
But, if it is used in a regular expression, PCRE will get this string as is. And since **n** is also special to PCRE, it will interpret that as a newline character, and BOOM, it "magicaly" matches a newline in a string.
Check the escape sequences here: [Escape Sequences](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)

As I said in the beginning, things area not exactly as I tried to explain here, but I really hope it helps (and not make it more confusing than it already is).