# regex visual studio

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I was planning to use the following regex to capture path and name of a file:

```
std::regex capture_path_name_file("(.+)\\([^\\]+)\\.[^\\]+$");
```

but when running (i'm using visual studio) i get the regex error

```
error_brack: the expression contained mismatched [ and ]
```

Trying to pinpoint the cause i tried the following regex:

```
std::regex test("[^\\]")
```

and I got the same error.

I have tested my regex in [regex101.com](https://www.regex101.com/r/mI9fS3/2) (with the slight difference that i had to use `\.` instead of `\\.`)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: In C++ syntax, `"[^\\]"` means `[^\]`, which in regex is a mismatched `[`. If you mean to create a character class of ‘not backslash’, you'll have to escape it once for C++ and once for regex, i.e. `[^\\\\]`.

Comment: It's for php but should answer your question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14783396/4181011

Comment: See [this demo](https://ideone.com/UpArVo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you have is because `\\` is treated as 1 literal `\` symbol in regular string literals. [Biffen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418066/biffen) explained it well in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34895119/regex-visual-studio#comment57527144_34895119), `[^\\]` is treated as `[^\]`, the `]` is treated as a literal `]` and not the closing character class delimiter (and there is no matching `]` to close the character class further).

The right answer is: use [`_splitpath_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8e46eyt7.aspx).

And if you want to further play with regex, you can fix it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::regex rex1(R"((.+?)([^\\.]+\.[^\\.]+)$)");
    std::smatch m;
    std::string str = "c:\\Python27\\REGEX\\test_regex.py";
    if (regex_search(str, m, rex1)) {
        std::cout << "Path: " << m[1] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "File name: " << m[2] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Using raw string literals, you can avoid the majority of issues related to escaping. Use `R"((.+?)([^\\.]+\.[^\\.]+)$)"`, it will match and capture into Group 1 the file folder path, and it will capture into Group 2 the file name with extension. Note that the extension must be present.

Comment: I would strongly argue that `_splitpath_s` is _not_ a good solution, but rather to iterate through an instance of [`std::tr2::path`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874769%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) (`std::experimental::path` in VC++ 2015).